# Map table with duplicated columns to two instances of same class

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a database that looks something like the following.  Yeah, I know, I inherited a bad design, but it can't be changed right now.  Basically, each customer can have primary and secondary contact information:

## Customer

- id
- customer_number
- [other stuff]

## ContactInfo

- customer_id
- primary_name
- primary_email
- primary_phone
- secondary_name
- secondary_email
- secondary_phone
- updated_at

I would like my Entity Framework 6 domain model to look like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }

    public ContactInfo PrimaryContactInfo { get; set; }
    public ContactInfo SecondaryContactInfo { get; set; }
}

public class ContactInfo
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to set up the mapping such that this is possible?  In essence, map the columns "primary_*" to one instance of ContactInfo, the columns "secondary_*" to another instance, and map some of the columns to both instances?

Alternatively, can the fields be mapped to two instances of a complex type:

```
public class ContactInfo
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public SingleContactInfo Primary { get; set; }
    public SingleContactInfo Secondary { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class SingleContactInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to guess no. Typically, whenever you have a Navigation Property, you're indicating a FK reference. With two Navigation Properties, I'd expect two FKs, but you really only want one. For EF, an Entity should be analogous to a record in the DB, not a partial record like you're asking for

Comment: @Vlad274 - that's what I thought.  What about adding a second level, keeping a top-level AllContactInfo class that has the foreign key, and mapping the columns to two instances of a complex type?  I'll modify my question.

Comment: You could create another table CostumerContactInfo and save the UserId and ContactId. That way the user can have multiple contacts. For that, you need to have a Collection of Contacts in the Customer entity. I also imagine that what you want is not possible (not in a "regular" way)

Comment: @jpgrassi I would certainly prefer doing that (cleaning up the data structure to have a true one-to-many relationship between Customer and Contact Info) but the ripple effect in a related desktop application would be too costly right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution (inheritance) can't be done, because it's impossible to save two entities in an inheritance scheme to one database record.

The second solution (complex type) does work, but you have to sacrifice the ability to address `ContactInfo`s as independent entities and to include `updated_at` in your model. (Because `updated_at` can't be mapped twice to one complex type property).

The only way I see to map entities to the data model while keeping `ContactInfo` as an independent entity set (almost) and the ability to read/write `updated_at`, is by *table splitting*.

In this mapping, table `ContactInfo` is split into two entities `ContactInfoPrimary` and `ContactInfoSecondary`. `Customer` has a 1:1 association to `ContactInfoPrimary`, which *contains* `ContactInfoSecondary`.

This is what it looks like:

The classes:

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual ContactInfoPrimary ContactInfoPrimary { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ContactInfo
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}

public class ContactInfoPrimary : ContactInfo
{
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual ContactInfoSecondary ContactInfoSecondary { get; set; }
}

public class ContactInfoSecondary : ContactInfo
{ }
```

The mappings:

```
class CustomerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        ToTable("Customer");
        HasKey(c => c.Id);
        Property(c => c.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
            .HasColumnName("id");
        Property(c => c.CustomerNumber)
            .HasColumnName("customer_number");
        HasOptional(c => c.ContactInfoPrimary).WithRequired(ci => ci.Customer);
    }    
}

class ContactInfoPrimaryMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ContactInfoPrimary>
{
    public ContactInfoPrimaryMap()
    {
        ToTable("ContactInfo");
        HasKey(ci => ci.CustomerId);
        Property(ci => ci.CustomerId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)
            .HasColumnName("customer_id");
        Property(ci => ci.UpdatedAt).HasColumnName("updated_at");
        Property(ci => ci.Name).HasColumnName("primary_name");
        Property(ci => ci.Email).HasColumnName("primary_email");
        Property(ci => ci.Phone).HasColumnName("primary_phone");

        // This, and the ToTable statements, define the table splitting.
        HasRequired(ci => ci.ContactInfoSecondary).WithRequiredPrincipal();
    }
}

class ContactInfoSecondaryMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ContactInfoSecondary>
{
    public ContactInfoSecondaryMap()
    {
        ToTable("ContactInfo");
        HasKey(ci => ci.CustomerId);
        Property(ci => ci.CustomerId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)
            .HasColumnName("customer_id");
        Property(ci => ci.Name).HasColumnName("secondary_name");
        Property(ci => ci.Email).HasColumnName("secondary_email");
        Property(ci => ci.Phone).HasColumnName("secondary_phone");
    }
}
```

And the context:

```
public partial class TestSO : DbContext
{
    public TestSO() : base("name=TestSO")
    { }

    public virtual DbSet<ContactInfoPrimary> ContactInfoes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustomerMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ContactInfoPrimaryMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ContactInfoSecondaryMap());
    }
}
```

Now you can create a `Customer` with contact info like so:

```
var cis = new ContactInfoSecondary
            {
                Name = "Name2",
                Email = "email2",
                Phone = "phone2"
            };
var cip = new ContactInfoPrimary
            {
                Name = "Name1",
                Email = "email1",
                Phone = "phone1",
                UpdatedAt = DateTime.Today,
                ContactInfoSecondary = cis
            };
var cst = new Customer
            {
                ContactInfoPrimary = cip,
                CustomerNumber = "number-nine"
            };
context.Customers.Add(cst);
context.SaveChanges();
```

And this is how to fetch customers with all information:

```
context.Customers.Include(c => c.ContactInfoPrimary.ContactInfoSecondary)
```

Or contact information separately:

```
context.ContactInfoes.Include(c => c.ContactInfoSecondary)
```

You see why I said that you can *almost* get `ContactInfo` independently. Not entirely. You can only get the secondaries through the primaries.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK removing the CustomerID and Customer references from your ContactInfo class, then you could try the following:

Register ContactInfo as a ComplexType:

```
modelBuilder.ComplexType<ContactInfo>();
```

Define specific names for the columns as per each instance on the Customer object (I am just showing how to do this for the name property):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Property(p => p.PrimaryContactInfo.Name).HasColumnName("primary_name");
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Property(p => p.SecondaryContactInfo.Name).HasColumnName("secondary_name");
```

Comment: I ended up using my alternative solution as documented at the bottom of the question.  But yes, it looks like using a complex type is the only way to go without changing the database schema.